# Filter the proportions greater than a number in Dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data,

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
mtcars = tbl_dt(mtcars)
```

I am using the following command,

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = (n / sum(n)) * 100)
```

I get the following output,

```
am gear  n     freq
 0    3 15      79
 0    4  4      21
 1    4  8      62
 1    5  5      38
```

Now I want to filter all the entries corresponding to ones which are less than freq 25. For example, if I give 25 as value, I want to remove all the 4 entries corresponding to proportions less than 25. The output should contain, 28 entries instead for 32. Is it possible to filter out all the entries corresponding to proportions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in a single chain if you use `mutate`, rather than `summarise`, to count the number of rows in each group.

```
min.freq = 0.25

mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  group_by(am) %>%
  filter(n/n() > min.freq) %>% select(-n)
```

> ```
>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
> ...
> 26 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
> 27 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
> 28 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
> ```